# Remove top k duplicate lines from shell

Tags: linux, shell

I have a csv file that looks like this

```
John,Smith, 2, 3
John,Smith, 2, 3
John,Smith, 1, 4
John,Smith, 6, 2
Adam,Brown, 2, 3
Adam,Brown, 5, 6
Adam,Brown, 1, 1
Thom,Bow, 1, 5
```

I'd like to keep the top `k` lines for every occurrence of first and last name, in order of appearance. The output with k=2 should be

```
John,Smith, 2, 3
John,Smith, 2, 3
Adam,Brown, 2, 3
Adam,Brown, 5, 6
Thom,Bow, 1, 5
```

The number of columns is not necessarily the same for all rows. However, the first two columns are always present.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is your friend here:

```
awk -F\, -v k=2 'a[$1, $2]++<k+0' file
```

**Results**

```
John,Smith, 2, 3
John,Smith, 2, 3
Adam,Brown, 2, 3
Adam,Brown, 5, 6
Thom,Bow, 1, 5
```

**Explanation**

To pass the max number of iterations: `-v k=2`

We use an associative [array](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Array-Basics), it's *key* is formed by the first two fields of the row `$1, $2` , these fields are separated by the *comma* character: `-F\,`

The value of this *array* for that `$1, $2` key is **increased** every time we found the same key: `a[$1, $2]++`

In `awk` if an *expression* satisfies a condition the **default** action is to print the current row / line, so we’re only going to show a maximum of `k`itinerations of the *founded key*: `<k+0`

**NOTE**: `+0` in `k+0` is a safety mechanism to force a integer value in `k` var.

**Unsorted file grouped by surname Example**

```
$ cat file
John,Smith, 2, 3
Adam,Brown, 2, 3
John,Smith, 2, 3
Thom,Bow, 1, 5
Adam,Brown, 5, 6
Adam,Brown, 1, 1
John,Smith, 1, 4
John,Smith, 6, 2
```

Using sort by second field:

```
$ awk -F\, -v k=2 'a[$1, $2]++<k+0' file|sort -r -t, -k 2
John,Smith, 2, 3
John,Smith, 2, 3
Adam,Brown, 5, 6
Adam,Brown, 2, 3
Thom,Bow, 1, 5
```

Comment: could you possibly add a short explanation? Thank you,

Comment: last question. would it be possible to do the same when the rows are not "grouped" by first/last name, without changing the order of the given file? The reason is that rows are pre-sorted according to column 3 first and then column 4, and I want to pick the top k for every first/last name

Comment: Yes, you dont need it to be grouped, `awk` will print the rows as its found in the source file, the order will not change.

Comment: what is the meaning of <k+0? I mean, why +0?

Comment: Check the update, and try to run this xP : `awk -F\, -v k=dummy 'a[$1$2]++<k' file`

Comment: `[$1 FS $2]` is better than `[$1$2]`

Comment: and `[$1,$2]` is better than `[$1 FS $2]` --  it's easier to look at.

Comment: it does not seem to work. I see rows with same first/last being separated